# Is it possible for each vector bundle to find another one that their direct sum is trivial on an affine?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

Given a smooth projective variety $X$ and a hyperplane section complement $U$. For any vector bundle $E$ on $X$, is it possible to find another vector bundle $F$ such that $E\oplus F$ is a trivial vector bundle on the affine scheme $U$?

Comment: Hints: you only need affineness; what nice property does the module associated to a locally free sheaf on an affine scheme have?

Comment: Well I know on affines projective modules are direct summands of free modules. The problem is whether the complement of the projective module (corresponding to $E|_{U}$) can be extended to a vector bundle on the projective variety $X$.

Comment: Ah, forgive me, I had not read this correctly and thought you were only working over $U$. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle $E(n)$ is globally generated for $n \gg 0$. Therefore, there is an exact sequence
$$
0 \to F \to \mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus m} \to E(n) \to 0.
$$
Since $\mathcal{O}_X(1)\vert_U \cong \mathcal{O}_U$, its restriction to $U$ takes the form
$$
0 \to F\vert_U \to \mathcal{O}_U^{\oplus m} \to E\vert_U \to 0.
$$
Finally,
$$
\mathrm{Ext}^1(E\vert_U,F\vert_U) = H^1(U,E^\vee \otimes F\vert_U) = 0
$$
since $U$ is affine, hence the second exact sequence splits, hence $E\vert_U \oplus F\vert_U$ is trivial.